# useState spread syntax

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I set setItemPressed({[itemid]: false, ...itemPressed}), the itemid doesn't change to false, but when I setItemPressed({[itemid]: false}) itemid cahnges to false, but all of the other ids get removed. How do I make it so the other ids stay and this one changes?

```
  const [itemPressed, setItemPressed] = useState({});
    const changeColor = (itemid) => {
    if(itemPressed.hasOwnProperty(itemid)){
      setItemPressed({[itemid]: false, ...itemPressed})
    }
    else{
    setItemPressed({...itemPressed, [itemid]: true});
  }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordering matters.

```
      setItemPressed({[itemid]: false, ...itemPressed})
```

should be flipped:

```
      setItemPressed({...itemPressed, [itemid]: false})
```

Whatever comes later overrides what came before.

**Edit**: The reason why the press doesn't work is because the key is always in the object. Setting it to false doesn't delete it, so `hasOwnProperty` will always return true after the first time it's pressed, and it'll always be set to false.

Here's how you should rewrite it to delete the key when it's unpressed:

```
 const [itemPressed, setItemPressed] = useState({});
    const changeColor = (itemid) => {
    // Create a copy of the state
    const newItemPressed = {...itemPressed};

    if(newItemPressed.hasOwnProperty(itemid)){
      // Delete the key from the object, this way you don't have unnecessary
      // keys still in there.
      delete newItemPressed[itemid];
    }
    else{
      newItemPressed[itemid] = true;
    }
    
    setItemPressed(newItemPressed);
}
```

Comment: It works, but when I press again it doesn't change back to true. How do I fix that?

Comment: It's because you're always doing `    if(itemPressed.hasOwnProperty(itemid)){`. This will **always** be true because `itemid` will always exist in the object. By setting it to false, doesn't mean it's deleted. The key still exists, just with a value of false. I'll update my answer to show how you should write that function

Comment: Please see the updated answer in my post

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the order of putting ...itemPressed and your property

```
const [itemPressed, setItemPressed] = useState({});
    const changeColor = (itemid) => {
    if(itemPressed.hasOwnProperty(itemid)){
      setItemPressed({...itemPressed,[itemid]: false,})
    }
    else{
    setItemPressed({...itemPressed, [itemid]: true});
  }}
```

Comment: Worked, but when I press the button again, it doesn't change back to true. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

you can set false in usestate like this

```
const [itemPressed , setItemPressed] = useState(false);
```

and then you setState like this:

```
setItemPressed(!itemPressed);
```

it will change state when you press